# how can i click this element on the discord page with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[Discord Element To Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wxuY.png)

I am trying to click the button on the discord login page, i have tried finding the class however the class is random every session i believe and i have tried finding the ID but it does not have an ID.

My goal is to insert text (i've done that already) and click the "Login" button

````
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:/Users/sexyv/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://discord.com/login")
email_box = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="email")
password_box = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="password")
submit_button = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="login-button")

def login(driver, email_box, password_box):
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    email_box.send_keys("johnsonkalel15@gmail.com")
    password_box.send_keys("Kalel12345shjd")
    


login(driver=driver,email_box=email_box, password_box=password_box)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to `click` on `login` button use the below locator and click on it.

**CSS Selector**

```
button[type='submit']
```

**OR XPATH**

```
//button[@type='submit']
```